# What consequences would a senator who does not attend the impeachment trial face?

Tags: united-states, election, senate-rules

I have seen the argument that impeachment was not about removing Trump, but rather it was about keeping presidential candidates who also happen to be senators off the campaign trail, especially Bernie Sanders.

Assuming this really is the motive, it seems this tactic could only be effective if skipping the trial has serious consequences.  Otherwise Sanders et. al. may decide its more damaging to miss campaign rallies, and will choose to accept whatever slap-on-the-wrist they face for being absent.

So what consequences could they face, and who would impose them?

Edit: The answers to this [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49496/are-all-u-s-senators-required-to-attend-the-impeachment-trial) state that senators who skip impeachment may be arrested.  But this may or may not be a serious consequence depending on how long they can be held and what they can be charged with.

Comment: I would like an answer more focused on what the consequences would be.  The first answer quotes the NY Post saying "compel means arrest".  But arrest under what charge?  How long could they be held?

Comment: The imperative "compel the attendance of absent Senators" means only that they are brought to the Senate floor. _See_ [Senate Police Seize Packwood for Quorum Call](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1988-02-25-mn-45210-story.html) for a similar case. Clearly, if they are out of town, the "arrest" is more difficult.

Comment: @Ryan_L  being arrested doesn't necessarily mean "taken into custody" ; as an example, I can be arrested for speeding and not be taken into custody.